# best way to add logic around django version?

Tags: python, django

With the new `django.apps` in Django 1.7, I'm now encountering a situation where the Django version will trigger the way an `__init__` file handles configuration. For example:

```
from django.apps import AppConfig
...
```

Will not work on 1.6 and below. So it would be useful to check the version. My question: what's the canonical way for checking the version of Django?

String comparison? (this just seems funky)

```
if django.get_version() >= '1.7.0'
```

Or accessing the version tuple?

```
major_version == django.VERSION[0]
minor_version == django.VERSION[1]
if major_version >= 1 and minor_version >= 7
```

Obviously, the second method would fail on 2.0, and we could just say *meh... I'll cross that bridge when I get there*, but that certainly does not seem elegant.

Is there a third option? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sequences in Python are compared naturally.

```
>>> (2, 0, 0) > (1, 7)
True
>>> (1, 6) > (1, 7)
False
>>> (1, 6, 2) > (1, 7)
False
```

Comment: Right; well that makes sense now. I should be able to do: `django.VERSION >= (1,7)`